# Can somebody help me out. I am facing problem in writing this code with Python

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

We're working with a list of flowers and some information about each one. The create_file function writes this information to a CSV file. The contents_of_file function reads this file into records and returns the information in a nicely formatted block. Fill in the gaps of the contents_of_file function to turn the data in the CSV file into a dictionary using DictReader.

```
import os
import csv

# Create a file with data in it
def create_file(filename):
  with open(filename, "a") as file:
    file.write("name,color,type\n")
    file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
    file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
    file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
    file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
    file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")

# Read the file contents and format the information about each row
def contents_of_file(filename):
  return_string = ""

  # Call the function to create the file 
  create_file(filename)

  # Open the file
  with open(filename) as file:
    # Read the rows of the file into a dictionary
    f = csv.reader(file)
    # Process each item of the dictionary
    for row in f:
      name, color, type = row
      return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(row["color"], row["name"], row["type"])
  return return_string

#Call the function
print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))

[See the error][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UycSc.jpg
```

Comment: Please include your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: I have added the code just now.. Sorry I never used stackoverflow for asking questions.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This would be answer, @Pratik Panda in your code you have used reader() but in problem statement they said must use **DictReader()**,

```
import os
import csv

# Create a file with data in it
def create_file(filename):
  with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write("name,color,type\n")
    file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
    file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
    file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
    file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
    file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")

# Read the file contents and format the information about each row
def contents_of_file(filename):
  return_string = ""

  # Call the function to create the file 
  create_file(filename)

  # Open the file
  with open(filename) as file:
    # Read the rows of the file into a dictionary
    f = csv.DictReader(file)
    # Process each item of the dictionary
    for row in f:
      return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(row["color"], row["name"], row["type"])
  return return_string

#Call the function
print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))
```

Answer (score 1):

So the problem you're facing is that the data type of `row` on `Line 26` is an `array` and not a `dict`. So if you use the `index` of the element instead of the `['keyName']` it'll work just fine.

Replace the below:

```
return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(row["color"], row["name"], row["type"])
```

With

```
return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(row[1], row[0], row[2])
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `String Interpolation` to make your code more readable:

```
return_string += f'a {row[1]} {row[0]} is {row[2]}\n'
```

If you want to use column names as indexes, you can use a `csv.DictReader()` instead of a `csv.reader()`

Comment: @PratikPanda please mark it as an answer for reference of others. You can do so by clicking the tick icon on the left of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here. Check out the solution I wrote.

```
import os
import csv

# Create a file with data in it
def create_file(filename):
  with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write("name,color,type\n")
    file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
    file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
    file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
    file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
    file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")

# Read the file contents and format the information 
about each row
def contents_of_file(filename):
  return_string = ""
  flower_dict = {}
  # Call the function to create the file 
  create_file(filename)

  #Open the file
  with open(filename) as file:
    # Read the rows of the file into a dictionary
    f = csv.DictReader(file)
    # Process each item of the dictionary
    for row in f:
      return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(row["color"], row["name"], row["type"])
  return return_string
#Call the function
print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))
```

Comment: just to update this is 'flower_dict' not require, else i think your code must work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line for `return_string`:

```
return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(row[0], row[1], row[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import csv

# Create a file with data in it
def create_file(filename):
   with open(filename, "w") as file:
     file.write("name,color,type\n")
     file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
     file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
     file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
     file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
     file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")

 # Read the file contents and format the information about each row
 def contents_of_file(filename):
   return_string = ""

   # Call the function to create the file 
   create_file(filename)

   # Open the file
   with open(filename) as file:
     # Read the rows of the file into a dictionary
     name = csv.DictReader(file)
     # Process each item of the dictionary
     for row in name:
        return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(row["color"], row["name"], row["type"])
   return return_string

#Call the function
print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
import csv

# Create a file with data in it
def create_file(filename):
  with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write("name,color,type\n")
    file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
    file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
    file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
    file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
    file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")

 # Read the file contents and format the information about each row
 def contents_of_file(filename):
   return_string = ""

   # Call the function to create the file 
   create_file(filename)

   # Open the file
   with open(filename) as file:
      # Read the rows of the file
      rows = csv.reader(file)
      rows = list(rows)
      # Process each row
      for row in rows:
        name,color,ty = row
        # Format the return string for data rows only
       if row !=rows[0]:

           return_string += "a {} {} is {}\n".format(color,name,ty)
   return return_string

 #Call the function
print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))
```